# How to write Laravel One to One relationship model and migration

Tags: laravel, relationship, one-to-one

With One To One relationship, I'm supposed to have only one `phone` entry per `user`.

1. So, why am I able to add multiple phone numbers ?
2. Does it mean that `App\User::find(1)->phone` only returns the first phone found in the database ?
3. Should I add a `unique` constraint to the `user_id` column in the phones migration ?

**User Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

**Phone model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Phone extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user that owns the phone.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

**Users table migration:**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Phone migration:**

```
Schema::create('phones', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('phone');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: Yes, you should add a `unique` constraint as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986148/laravel-one-to-one-relationship-becomes-one-to-many-relationship).

Answer (score 1):

```
Schema::create('phones', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->unique();
    $table->string('phone');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) So, why am I able to add multiple phone numbers?
**  While adding a phone number to the database, simply search if the current user has a phone number. If yes, then update it. Else, create a new one. Check [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

```
// If there is a user with id 2 then SET the phone to 7897897890.
// If no user with id 2 found, then CREATE one with user_id 2 and phone number to 7897897890
Phone::updateOrCreate(
    ['user_id' => 2],
    ['phone' => '7897897890']
);
```

2) Does it mean that App\User::find(1)->phone only returns the first phone found in the database?
**  As long as your relation is **hasOne**, you fetched data will be one where user_id = current user. If you are planning to have one phone number for each user throughout the project then **might I suggest** to simply add the phone number column to the users table.

3) Should I add a `unique` constraint to the `user_id` column in the phones migration?
**   **Yes**, you can. However, as I suggested in the second point, just have a phone column in the users table (if you want to, otherwise this will work too)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ....

In the User model, define the One-to-One relationship with the Phone model:

**User Model**

```
class User extends Model
    {
        public function phone()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(Phone::class);
        }
    }
```

In the Phone model, define the reverse relationship:

**Phone Model**

```
class Phone extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```